# Pass as input "System.Object" as dynamic json in POST API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-6.0

I want to pass "System.Object" as dynamic JSON as my input (my JSON has no specific schema) in POST API. I have recently migrated my entire application to **.net core 6.0** from **2.2**

Here is the code for my controller:

```
[HttpPost("GetNunjucksData")]
public IActionResult GetNunjucksData([FromBody]NunjucksDataModal modal)
{
    try
    {
        var list = new Nunjucks().GetNunjucksData(modal);

        Status = true;
        Message = "Success";

        var jsonData = new { Data = list, Status, Message };
        return Ok(jsonData);
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        Message = Ex.Message;
        var jsonData = new { Status, Message };
        return NotFound(jsonData);
    }
}

//modal

public class NunjucksDataModal
{
    public int web_id { get; set; }
    public int component_type_id { get; set; }
    public object json { get; set; }
}
```

Note: I don't want to pass JSON as String because I have implemented this functionality in multiple methods. The same JSON was working on **.net core 2.2**

Json for my input:

```
{
    "web_id": 1203,
    "component_type_id": 16,
    "json": {
        "product_id": "795770"
    }
}
```

Here is the attached image of the exact error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: unable to reproduce,It seems you added some special charater after "795770",please share your request in swagger

Comment: You can show respect for those who might help you by taking the few extra moments to be sure your code is well-formatted, rather than indented to the right in too small to read because it's in an image.